# End of Line not Reading - Stream Tokenize Java

Tags: java, stream

My program reads from a file using Stream Tokenizer and prints the contents. The if condition where it checks if it has reached the end of file isn't working.

```
public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception {
  FileReader fr = new FileReader("sample.txt");
    StreamTokenizer st = new StreamTokenizer(fr);
    System.out.printf("%26s","Student Marksheet");
    System.out.println(); 

     do{
         tokenType=st.nextToken();
     if(tokenType==StreamTokenizer.TT_WORD) System.out.print(st.sval+"      ");
      if(tokenType==StreamTokenizer.TT_NUMBER) System.out.print(st.nval+"      ");
      if(tokenType==StreamTokenizer.TT_EOL) System.out.println(); //this line is the problem
     } while(tokenType!=StreamTokenizer.TT_EOF); 
}
```

this is the text file

---

name eng phys chem comp

name1 5 4 3 2 1

lolk 5 2 1 4 100

Comment: This code works completely OK on my local machine.  What error are you getting?  I suspect that if there be an error, that it is related to some strangeness in your input file.

Comment: eolIsSignificant(false) is default .So,make it true and run the code it will work. when it is false next token will not return the TT_EOL. Refer my answer below.

Comment: @ Tim Biegeleisen let me know ,if this works.

Answer (score 2):

> **TT_EOL**

```
public final static int TT_EOL = '\n'
```

> Description
>
> This token type indicates that the end of a line has been reached. The value is not returned by nextToken() unless eolIsSignificant(true) has been called.

`eolIsSignificant(false)` is the default state. So, make it true and run the code it will work. when it is false next token will not return the TT_EOL.

check with following code.

```
     FileReader fr = new FileReader("input.txt");
                    StreamTokenizer st = new StreamTokenizer(fr);
                    st.eolIsSignificant(true);//add this line
                    System.out.printf("%26s","Student Marksheet");
                    System.out.println(); 
                    int  tokenType=0;
                     do{
                          tokenType=st.nextToken();
                     if(tokenType==StreamTokenizer.TT_WORD) System.out.print(st.sval+"      ");
                      if(tokenType==StreamTokenizer.TT_NUMBER) System.out.print(st.nval+"      ");
                      if(tokenType==StreamTokenizer.TT_EOL) System.out.println(""); //this line is the problem
                     } while(tokenType!=StreamTokenizer.TT_EOF); 
                }
```